# I see 'The background is pink!' in the console but it stubbornly remains white

Tags: sass, browserify

Using the example in their docs, I created the following:

entry.js:

```
require('./style.scss');
console.log('The background is pink!')
```

style.scss:

```
body {
  background: pink;
}
```

I then run this through browserify: `browserify -t sassify entry.js > bundle.js` and get this:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
require('./style.scss');

console.log('The background is pink!')

},{"./style.scss":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = "body {\n  background: pink; }\n";
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

I can see my css in there! But when I create a minimal html that loads the bundle, I see 'The background is pink!' in the console - but it stubbornly remains white. Am I forgetting anything? What does it take for the styles to actually show up?

index.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Pink!</h1>
  </body>
  <script src='bundle.js'></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In the sassify github [page](https://github.com/davidguttman/sassify) it says `Currently breaks in some cases on node 0.11.x with latest version (2.0.1) of node-sass as documented in node-sass issue #550. This is also the reason why node 0.11 is currently not supported. Use at your own risk (though no actual risk is involved, it might just not work).`</strike>

I too couldn't get it to work. As he says, it doesn't break anything. It just doesn't do anything at all.

You might want to try [cody-greene's scssify](https://github.com/cody-greene/scssify). All you need is: `npm i scssify -D`

And in place of `browserify -t sassify entry.js > bundle.js` you need `browserify -t scssify entry.js > bundle.js`

You just need to make sure you use `sassify@4.0.0`